# T-SQL Stored Procedure help: Getting a person's friends from Friends table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, stored-procedures, exists

I am having trouble with T-SQL. I am a beginner at T-SQL.

I have a database of friend entries. One column contains MemberA_ID, which is an integer ID for one of the friend's member ID in a pair of friends. Another column contains MemberB_ID, which is an integer ID for the other friend's member ID in a pair of friends.

So if Mary's ID is 1 and John's ID is 2, and they are friends, then a row in the Friends table would contain 1 and 2 (among other data).

I am trying to write a T-SQL stored procedure that takes in a member ID as input, and retrieves, for all the friends of that member, their memberID and username (username is stored in another table called MemberProfiles).

I am trying this code, but It is not being accepted.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetFriends (@ownMemberID [int])

    AS

    DECLARE @localFriendID_A AS INTEGER
    DECLARE @localFriendID_B AS INTEGER

    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT @localFriendID_B = MemberB_ID
        FROM Friends
        WHERE (StartDate IS NOT NULL) AND (EndDate IS NULL) 
        AND (RequestRejectDate IS NULL) AND (MemberA_ID = @ownMemberID)
    )
    BEGIN
        SELECT MemberID, VisibleUsername
        FROM MemberProfiles
        WHERE (MemberID = @localFriendID_B) 
    END

    ELSE IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT @localFriendID_A = MemberA_ID
        FROM Friends
        WHERE (StartDate IS NOT NULL) AND (EndDate IS NULL) 
        AND (RequestRejectDate IS NULL) AND (MemberB_ID = @ownMemberID)
    )
    BEGIN
        SELECT MemberID, VisibleUsername
        FROM MemberProfiles
        WHERE (MemberID = @localFriendID_A)
    END

    RETURN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with the above code is, you are trying to initialize while checking for the existence of a row...

you have to write the TSQL as below

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetFriends (@ownMemberID [int])

AS

DECLARE @localFriendID_A AS INTEGER
DECLARE @localFriendID_B AS INTEGER

SET @localFriendID_A = 0
SET @localFriendID_B = 0

SELECT @localFriendID_B = MemberB_ID
FROM Friends
WHERE (StartDate IS NOT NULL) AND (EndDate IS NULL) 
AND (RequestRejectDate IS NULL) AND (MemberA_ID = @ownMemberID)


SELECT @localFriendID_A = MemberA_ID
FROM Friends
WHERE (StartDate IS NOT NULL) AND (EndDate IS NULL) 
AND (RequestRejectDate IS NULL) AND (MemberB_ID = @ownMemberID)

IF ( @localFriendID_B <> 0 )
BEGIN
    SELECT MemberID, VisibleUsername
    FROM MemberProfiles
    WHERE (MemberID = @localFriendID_B) 
END
ELSE IF (@localFriendID_A <> 0 )
BEGIN
    SELECT MemberID, VisibleUsername
    FROM MemberProfiles
    WHERE (MemberID = @localFriendID_A)
END

RETURN
```